# Void argument in \title command

Tags: macros

In latex.ltx there are two lines concerning `\title`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\title[1]{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
```

I guess the second line is introduced to throw an error if the argument of `\title` is void like in `\title{}`, but I don’t understand how this achieved by the above code.

Comment: The code just checks if `\title` is not used.  If you do `\title{}` no error will be raised

Comment: While they appear out of order, \title replaces the default definition.

Answer (score 3):

When `\maketitle` is typesetting the title, it uses `\@title`.  By default, `\@title` is defined as:

```latex
\def\@title{\@latex@error{No \noexpand\title given}\@ehc}
```

so the document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle % <-- error here
\end{document}
```

will throw the error in `\@title`.

When you do `\title{<anything>}`, the `\title` command does:

```latex
\gdef\@title{<anything>}
```

so when typesetting, it will use `<anything>` instead of the default error message.  `<anything>` can really be anything, including empty, and there will be no error:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The document above produces a page with just `\today`'s date (and a warning saying `No \author given`).

Comment: Brilliant answer. I didn't know that you can use `\def` or `\gdef` twice on the same identifier  as `\def\foo{foo}`...`\def\foo{newfoo}`. That's different from LaTeX's `\newcommand` which can only be used once and needs `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @DietrichBaumgarten This is the main reason why LaTeX has `\newcommand` and users are discouraged to employ `\def`. Try `\def\fi{whatever}` in a document preamble and see! `;-)`

Comment: @DietrichBaumgarten `\def` is the TeX primitive for definitions (you can redefine anything with `\def`), and `\newcommand` (and many others) are just fancy wrappers around `\def` to prevent users from shooting themselves on the foot, like egreg just said.  At the user level it is recommended to use the higher-level `\newcommand` (or in recent LaTeX `\NewDocumentCommand`), while in lower-level applications `\def` is used when you are sure of what you are doing

Comment: @egreg I guess, I better don't try, but just for my information: `\renewcommand\fi{whatever}` would do the same trick. Right?

Comment: @DietrichBaumgarten It would, yes.  LaTeX doesn't have a "this shall not be redefined" list, so `\renewcommand` can break stuff if you're not careful